# Where should i add the code for an outer container in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress theme installed (SimplePress) and i would like to add an outer container to it, and i don't know exactly in which file should i add the code.

This is the code i tried to use:

```
    <div id="hbz_outer_container" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="hbz_drop_shadow">
```

This is an example of how i would like it to look: http://www.harpersbazaar.com

-- also a SCREENSHOT of exactly what i'm talking about http://i43.tinypic.com/2vchybm.jpg

i tried adding the code to some of the files, like scripts.php or other files from the theme, but i don't know if i have to change a file from the theme, or a file from wordpress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you mean by outer container?

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/2vchybm.jpg

Comment: Depends on the theme.... this question can't be answered like this

Comment: You mean the shadow effect around the container?

Comment: I think he mean shadow effect. I've posted an answer, but depends of the theme used.

Comment: @ koningdavid: i mentioned the theme: SimplePress

Comment: i dont mean the shadow around the container. i mean CONTAINER + SHADOW. and the QUESTION: IN WHICH FILE SHOULD I DO THE MODIFICATIONS ?

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ have you checked my answer?

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ I know it's simplepress, but we are not here so help you figure out a theme, post good code examples and we might be able to give you an answer

Comment: Simple Press? http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/simplepress/ or http://simple-press.com/ ???

Comment: the first one, that's the one

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ have you checked my answer again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand very well what are you doing to ask, but i think you vant something like this:

copy&paste in your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<style>
#shadowbox {
    margin: 5px auto 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
</style>
```

And copy&paste imediately after `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="shadowbox">
```

And imediately before `</body>` tag:

```
</div>
```

You Should do this in header.php and footer.php (in footer.php you should put ONLY `</div>`).

Comment: but if i do this in the 2 separate files header. and footer.php, won't that make 2 separate containers ?

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ okay... check my answer again

Comment: in footer.php you should put ONLY `</div>`

Comment: Thank you ITChristian :) it worked, i will now play with the attributes from here http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html

Comment: so i understand from here, that when the wp site runs, it makes somehow a simple concatenation of the header+footer.php, is this correct?

Comment: Thanks, too HoreaMihuţ. TRANSLATE: Multumesc si eu @HoreaMihuţ

Comment: can you please help me with another thing, if you maybe know the theme: where/how to add a divider jpeg between posts? i've tried 2 tutorials found online, and none of them worked :(

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ yes, sure, you must go to category.php and CTRL+F (find) read more text, and after the readmore put <span class="line"></span> (this generate the default separator line

Comment: and if i want to add a jpeg?  (i tried adding a class, and then adding it in the index.php) but didnt work. and i dont have category.php. but i found a lot of readmore in the style.css is there ok to add?

Comment: you can put <img src="YOUR URL"/>

Comment: i can't find anything (been looking for 1 hour). could you tell me to look for something else specific (because the readmore is deactivated). (would you be so kind to help me through teamviewer maybe?)

Comment: there are still some problems not solved, because in my google chrome, the site http://filldevoid.com/test has the shadowbox with your code is working perfectly, but if i make a zoom of 120% or more, it gets messed up. do you have any ideea how to fix this? here is a screenshot from me with 100% size http://i39.tinypic.com/x360xx.jpg

Comment: you can put width: auto; in #shadowbox {

Comment: it doesnţt work, here is the codeŞ #shadowbox {
    margin: 5px 450px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    initialHeight: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Horea, this depends on the templates your are using in the wp theme.
You'll have to edit those directly or use some filters (if available for that theme) to change their HTML structure.
The templates or filters are not something standard, you'll have to look for a documentation for SimplePress theme and edit your templates.
Please post a link to the theme codex, or documentation. It's possible you need a member account to access the documentation.